# Rotating vector elements by value greater than vector size?

Tags: c++, stl, rotation

Somewhat of a simple question, I'm rotating the order of elements in a vector using std::rotate:

```
std::vector<int> V {1,2,3,4};
std::rotate(V.rbegin(), V.rbegin() + K, V.rend());

//output: {4,1,2,3}
```

I'm getting a segmentation fault where K is >= V.size(), and I'm struggling to understand: 1) why this error is occurring? and 2) how I can perform a rotate operation with such a K value?

For example, a K of 6 should output {2,3,4,1}

Comment: You don't use 'K' in your sample code.  I am *deeply* suspicious of passing `V.end()` rather than `V.rend()` to the rotate.

Comment: According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate), _A precondition of this function is that [first, n_first) and [n_first, last) are valid ranges._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `K` is greater than `V.size()`, then `V.rbegin()+K` is an invalid iterator.  You need to reduce K by mod size.  Something like:

```
if (V.size() != 0) {
    std::rotate(V.rbegin(), V.rbegin() + (K % V.size()), V.rend());
}
```

Note the test for `size != 0` first  - otherwise you'll get division by zero.

Comment: Thanks for this Martin!

Answer (score 1):

`V.rebegin() + 6` is not a valid iterator. Which element would it point to? I will assume you want to rotate the vector by K elements. What you need to do is apply the modulo operator to find out which value should be at the front of the vector.

```
std::vector<int> V {1,2,3,4};
const auto K = 4 % V.size();
std::rotate(V.rbegin(), V.rbegin() + K, V.rend());
```

I'm not sure why you expect that K of 6 should result in {2,3,4,1}, it gives {3,4,1,2}. Perhaps I've misunderstood the question.

Edit: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41469671/7359094) about checking the size first.